# if statement to test 2 string but there isn't output?

Tags: python, regex, if-statement

My goal here is trying to match the list of strings against list of ints:

For example my list of strings: `wholelookup[uniprotID] = [A177T,I126T,M418T]`.

My list of ints: `lookup[uniprotID] = [177,126,418]`.

If there is a match then I would like to print the token in wholelookup.

Here is what i have so far but it didn't print anything as the result:

```
for item in lookup[uniprotID]:
    for names in wholelookup[uniprotID]:
        if start <= item <= end and re.match(item, names) :
            item, start, end = map(int, (item, start, end))
            print names
```

Comment: start? end? and why do you map?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath because lookup is a string not int thats why i need to make it int.. so that i compare it with others

Comment: Are you comparing strings with `start <= item <= end`  ? Is that what you want? Don't you want to compare numbers?

Comment: @MarcodeWit i want to compare if item in the range of start and end.. item should be number when i compare it with start and end

Answer (score 0):

`match` tries to match from the beginning. Also: you do not want to match a `1` to for instance  `a321a` .

You could use 're.match(r'\w'+str(item)+r'\w', names)' instead of `re.match(item, names)`

Or use `re.search`:

```
re.search(r'\d+',names).group(0)==item
```

Comment: that still doesn't work.. i got this as error:SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

Answer (score 0):

Why use a regex at all?

Assuming `start` and `end` are already ints and `item` is a string, try this:

```
for item in lookup[uniprotID]:
    if start <= int(item) <= end: continue
    for names in wholelookup[uniprotID]:
        if str(item) in names :
            print names
```

Comment: i don't get if str(names) in item: <-- names is already a string and item is an it since you changed it .. so this won't work

Comment: look at it now -- I had `item` and `names` switched on that if-statement.